# use telnet or ssh in a web application

Tags: javascript, java, web, ssh, telnet

I am new to web application development and now want to implement an function. Let me describe it:
    There is a remote machine or server, I can telnet or ssh to it and run some commands on the server using tools such as Putty or terminal. Now, I want to build a dialog box or input box in my web application, and users can use this box to ssh or telnet to the machine and run commands.
    Any comments about this idea? Thanks so much.

Comment: I am guessing you are using servlet and stuff and I am also assuming you know how to get data from a web page. If my above assumptions are correct then you can Runtime.getRuntime().exec to execute external shell commands in java.

Comment: Hi Jay, thanks your reply. As you mentioned I can use Runtime.getRuntime().exec to run external commands in java. But I want to use ssh to connect to a remote machine, and then interact with this machine in a web page. So how can I send command and receive msg from that machine?

Comment: is this what you are looking for: https://www.npmjs.com/package/web-terminal